# how can i change a class method name with decorators (python)?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, decorator

I want to change the method name from CamelCase to snake_case with a decorator, i tried this but it didn't work:

```
def snakecase(newname):
    def decorator(method):
          method.__name__ = newname
          return method
    return decorator

class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

@snakecase('increase_years')
def IncreaseYears(self, n_years):
    self.age += n_years
```

Anybody knows how to do it? Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me... why don't you just *write it in snake case*? Not sure if a decorator is really what you want here...

Comment: Your formatting is out - indent your class method another 4 spaces. You would be better off with a generic class decorator that created a duplicate method that points to your old method. The way you're trying to do it won't work.

Comment: thank you @RobertSeaman I get your idea about the generic class decorator with the same method but a different name.. The problem of the indent was when I transcribed the code here :< in the program it is ok.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is an example of a decorator that changes the name of the method, it can't be edited. thanks anyway